# Replace legacy column with a relation

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have a blog app on **Yii2** with a really old DB

I replaced  the text column `post.author` with a relation `post.author_id`.

For support reasons, the old column is active.

Now when I try to use  `$post->author->name` i get the  string column first, instead of the relation ...
Using the getter works fine  `$post->getAuthor()->name` , but this will be hard to maintain.

Is there some standard solution for this, to ignore the `post.author` **property**,
and to favor the Author **relation** instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the relation. If you rename the method `getAuthor` to `getPostauthor` the relation property will become `postauthor` (automatically) and you can fetch it via `$post->postauthor->name`

Answer (score 1):

1. $post->getAuthor() returns ActiveQuery and you can't do $post->getAuthor()->name.
2. You may add getter to your model:

   public function getAuthorName() {
      $author = $post->getAuthor()->one();
      return $author ? $author->name : null ;
   }
3. Or, rename the relation.